# Center of a ring matrix

Tags: ring-theory

I have the following ring matrix:

Ep=

```
    a     b
    pc   pu+v
```

where a,b,c,u,v belongs to Zp     where p is a prime

now the center of this matrix is:

Z(Ep)=

```
    x   0    
    0   py+x
```

where x,y belongs to Zp

**My Question** is how the center was calculated?

Thank you so much for the help

Comment: What do you mean by “Zp”?

Comment: Zp is a finite field

Comment: So $pc=pu=0$, isn't it?

Comment: yes you are right

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $\mathbb{Z}_p$ means the field with $p$ elements, then your ring is
$$
R=\left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & v
\end{bmatrix}
\;\middle|\;\; a,b,v\in\mathbb{Z}_p
\right\}
$$
A matrix $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x&y\\0&z\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ is in the center if
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & v
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&z\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0&z\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
0 & v
\end{bmatrix}
$$
*for all $a,b,v\in\mathbb{Z}_p$*; in other words, doing the products and comparing each entry,
$$
\begin{cases}
ax=xa\\
ay+bz=xb+yv\\
vz=zv
\end{cases}
$$
The first and third equalities hold, so what we must have is
$$
bx+(v-a)y-bz=0
$$
for all $a,b,v$.

Now use particular values of $a$, $b$ and $v$ to reach the conclusion.

> Setting $b=0$, $v=1$, $a=0$ we get $y=0$.
>
> Setting $a=0$, $v=0$ and $b=1$ we get $x=z$.The center is the set of scalar matrices.

---

Note that this doesn't use any special property of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so the argument works for any triangular matrix ring with coefficients in a commutative ring.

> If the coefficient ring is not commutative, the first and third equation tell us that $x$ and $z$ must be in the center of the coefficient ring. Setting $b=0$, $v=1$, $a=0$ in the middle one again says $y=0$, while $a=0$, $v=0$ and $b=1$ gives $x=z$. So in this case the center is the set of scalar matrices with coefficients in the center of the coefficient ring.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.If I took b=0,a=0,v=1 and y=0 this will give me [0 0;0 z] matrix. And b=1,a=0,v=0 and x=z give me [0 z;0 0] am I correct or not. Neither of them look like the center in the question. If my comment is not accurate sorry my major is CS not Mathematics.

Comment: @Student $x$, $y$ and $z$ are your unknowns, so you mustn't set them to particular values; only $a$, $b$ and $v$ are free to receive any value you want.

Comment: Regarding the center matrix in the question, why does py exist in the fourth position? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Student I can't know the precise text of the exercise; I made some guesses based on the information you gave.